# How to make rounded corners in css on different background

Tags: css, graphics

I want to create rounded corners of the section (I can do it with border-radius), but those sections intersect with each other and besides border radius theres this weird cut from the other section (see image)
Is there any way I can code it without using pictures of those sections?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve that using the `:after` pseudo element for the top section and bring that element back using `z-index` so it won't overlap the bottom section.

Here's an example:

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.top-section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #1B2149;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.top-section:after {
  content: " ";
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.bottom-section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-radius: 0 25px 0 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-section"></div>
  <div class="bottom-section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an element with absolute position with a pseudo-element and using a background and transparent combination create a curve and place it using absolute positioning.

however, in this case you can get the result with a much simpler solution.

All you need to do is wrap each area within a div that has the other background and show it with a border radius.

```css
#container {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.placeholder {
  height: 200px;
}
#top_div_back {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#top_div_front {
  background-color: #1a2048;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}
#bottom_div_back {
  background-color: #1a2048;
}
#bottom_div_front {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top_div_back">
    <div id="top_div_front" class="placeholder">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom_div_back">
    <div id="bottom_div_front" class="placeholder">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is by far the easiest and most stable solution for your needs.